# C++ MIDI File Change Instrument

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, instruments, midi

Is there a way to play a MIDI file using C++ in MSVC 2008 and change the instrument that is playing? i.e., can I play a .mid file of a few measures of piano, but change the piano sound to an electric guitar?

EDIT: Sorry I was not specific enough!! I am using Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth as my synthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mciSendString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Multimedia Command Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What command would I use with mciSendString to change the instrument sound that the file is playing?

Comment: ` mciSendString("play C:\\<full_path>",NULL,0,NULL);` and
` mciSendString("stop C:\\<full_path>",NULL,0,NULL);`

Comment: No, I mean after I call mciSendString("play .....), how can I change the sound of the MIDI file that is playing? i.e, I am playing a sonata through the MIDI mapper with the sound of a piano, but I want to change it to the sound of a guitar.

Answer (score 0):

If the instrument supports it, you should send a program change message to change the sound. Otherwise, you are probably looking at this problem the wrong way and should use multiple instruments instead.

Comment: I am not actually sending the MIDI commands to an instrument, but to the built in Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth

Comment: A software synthesizer is sometimes called a "virtual instrument". As long as you are sending MIDI to it, it's an instrument. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

http://protodesign-inc.com/source/MIDI.htm

The functionality you are looking for is implemented in MIDI.cpp. There is also a testing console app available:

http://protodesign-inc.com/source/MIDIplay_X.htm

Answer (score 0):

From your post, I'm assuming that you already have written code that reads in the events from the MIDI file and is outputting them to the device in real time.  So to change the sound you need a MIDI program change event.  You can find a list of the GM sounds [here](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/gm1sound.php) (note that GS is a superset of GM) and the definitions of the MIDI events [here](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php).

If you want to change the program on channel 1 to a distortion guitar then you'll need to output the bytes (in hex):

```
C0 1E
```

The 'C' is the prefix for program change events, the 0 refers to channel 1 (note that we usually refer to midi channels 1-16 but the MIDI events count the channel number from zero).  And 1E is program 31 (again, they're usually expressed as 1-128 but the midi events count from zero).